# Expected Number of roots in $\mathbb D (0;r)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, random-functions

In the literature about roots of  random polynomials there are many results about the  expected  number of real roots of a complex polynomial building on Kac formula  especially in the  the asymptotic cases as the degree of polynomial becomes large  .I am new to the field and I wonder whether there are are some know results or approaches   and the about computing the expected number of roots,real or complex , of a random polynomial  in a disc $\sum_0^n a_k z^k$ inside a disc   $D (0;r)\, r>0,$ in terms of coefficients $a_k `s $ and $n $ and  $ r $(exactly or approximately)  where $ r$ is the radius of  the disc  May be,this is a well -studied problem but I could not find some relevant sources .To be specific,let us assume  the coefficients are iid standard normal variables.
I would be highly obliged for any help/hints/links

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by random polynomial. You never state what distribution the coefficient a_k is assumed to have.

Comment: I meant for a given ensemble of polynomilas with a particicular distribution on ceofficients.say the coeeficients are iid standard random variates

Comment: I have made an edit